# Backbone.js View not showing in browser after render call

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, cordova, backbone-views

JS code below

Model

```
var EntryName = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        name : ""
    },
});
```

Model Collection

```
var EntryNames = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : EntryName,
    initialize : function() {

    }
});
```

ModelView

```
var EntryNameView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'li',
    // Cache the template function for a single item.
    entrynametpl : _.template('<li><a href="#" ></a></li>'),
    // Re-render.
```

Render function

```
    render : function() {
        this.$el.html(this.entrynametpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

});
```

ModelCollectionView

```
var EntryNamesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //      tagName: "ul",
    //      className: "nav-search",
    el : $('#entriestree'),
    initialize : function() {
        //this.template = _.template($('#entries-template').html());
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
```

Render function

```
        render : function() {
    var item, self = this;
    //var template = $("#item-template");
    this.collection.each(function(entry) {
        item = new EntryNameView({
            model : entry
        });
        self.$el.append(item.render().el);
    });
    console.log($(this.el));
    return this;
}    
});
```

Model Collection

Model Collection  This is where and how i call render.

```
function onDeviceReady() 
        {  
//          console.log("Opening panel");
            $("#nav-panel").panel( "open");
            console.log("creating collection");
            var donuts = new EntryNames();
            donuts.reset([  {"name" : "Boston Cream"},  {"name" : "Lemon-Filled"},  {"name" : "Rusty Iron Shavings"}]);
            console.log("created collection");
            var donutCollectionView = new EntryNamesView({collection : donuts});
            donutCollectionView.render();
            $("#nav-panel" ).trigger( "updatelayout" );
        }
```

Model Collection

The HTML code is below Model Collection

```
<body>
<div id="panel-fixed-page1" class="jqm-demos ui-responsive-panel"
    data-url="panel-fixed-page1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="f" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="d">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="ui-btn-active" href="#" data-         theme="a">Entry</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="a">Addresses</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-                               theme="a">Attachments</a></li>

             <li><a href="#" datatheme="a">Delivery Collection</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /navbar -->
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div class="jqm-content" data-role="content">
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->
    <div id="nav-panel" data-role="panel"
        data-position-fixed="true">
        <li><a href="#" data-rel="close" >INBOX</a></li>
        <ul id="entriestree" class="nav-search" data-role="listview" data-                      theme="a">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
      </body>
```

Model Collection

Model Collection

Comment: there's some html errors here, li is not in a ul...

Comment: no console errors, I don't see any html errors...ul is the collectionview container (present in the markup as entriestree) and li is the modelview page (not present in the html markup, just in the js file),  I added the <%= name %> no luck

Answer (score 1):

In your `EntryNamesView.render`, `this` is not pointing to the `view`, because it is inside `each` callback function scope. Try change it to use a `self`:

```
render : function() {
    var item, self = this;
    //var template = $("#item-template");
    this.collection.each(function(entry) {
        item = new EntryNameView({
            model : entry
        });
        self.$el.append(item.render().el);
    });
    console.log($(this.el));

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Cannot think of anything else then, do you have them some where online? or something like jsfiddle ?

Comment: still battling with this so far...slight progress though..I changed the line with self to  $("#entriestree").append(item.render().el),  and it worked.  I also debugged the js using visual studio (add onload event to body and called deviceready function), and noticed at breakpoint that the EntryNamesView didn't seem to be picking up the correct element

Comment: @user2275941 it seems working fine on my computer, but I do see some strange things. 1. in `EntryNameView` you put a `<li/>` inside `<li/>`, you may want delete the duplicate li in template. 2. I am not sure why you call `_.bindAll(this, 'render');` inside `EntryNamesView`, seems that doesn't do any thing.

Comment: @user2275941 Although those little thing should not prevent your view been rendered. I guess there are some environment setting I am missing.

Comment: @user2275941 one more thing.... In order to make it work, I removed `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` and `$("#nav-panel").panel("open");`, then call `onDeviceReady()` manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your _.underscore template has no placeholder variables:

```
entrynametpl : _.template('<li><a href="#" ></a></li>') //renders empty li's
```

correct this to:

```
entrynametpl: _.template('<li><a href="#"><%= name %></a></li>')
```

Comment: made this change still no luck

Answer (score 0):

okay i figured out the issue,  I set the view's element "el" property outside of the constructor (the initialize function), so it was never getting set with the proper dom element because the dom element came after the script reference in the html file.  once i moved the script import to the end of the page, voila life is good..silly mistakes cost you sooo much time!!!

Comment: ALL THREE are issues then, not just your last bug.